# How often User Group Policies are applied

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, active-directory, group-policy, domain

I have just a quick question, if I'm right:

Currently I have GroupPolicies for Machines (and their settings) and for Users (and their settings) in my Domain.
I know, that the Machine-Policies are pulled and running every 90 minutes on my servers.
But am I right, that the User-Policies are only pulled on the Users Logon? Or where/how can I check this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Using literally any search engine: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms812018.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct in that user group policies are updated upon user logon, but they are also automatically updated in the background every 60 to 180 minutes (one hour plus or minus thirty minutes).

It bears mentioning that there is a group policy that will allow you to change the user group policy background refresh period:

```
User Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\Group Policy\Group Policy refresh interval for users
```

Also, user group policy can be forcefully updated for the user by entering the following at the command line:

```
gpupdate /force
```

Answer (score 0):

```
By default, user Group Policy is updated in the background every 90
minutes, with a random offset of 0 to 30 minutes.
```

[Group Policy refresh interval for users | Microsoft Developer Network](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms812018.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

you have to open cmd as administrator and type "gpupdate /force" and user has at least to log off and log on again.

Otherwise to take effect you have to reset server